# must we render serialized data to json before sending response? DRF

Tags: json, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, response

The answer to this question is confusing me. 
[Multiple Models in Django Rest Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35485085/multiple-models-in-django-rest-framework)

the answer is to a question of sending multipule models in a response. I have the same use case.

the author of the answer has this:

```
def get(self, request, format=None, **kwargs):
    cart = get_cart(request)
    cart_serializer = CartSerializer(cart)
    another_serializer = AnotherSerializer(another_object)

    return Response({
        'cart': cart_serializer.data,
        'another': another_serializer.data,
        'yet_another_field': 'yet another value',
    })
```

but I am keeping with the documentation.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#serializing-objects

EXAMPLE FROM DOCS
    serializer = CommentSerializer(comment)
    serializer.data
    # {'email': 'leila@example.com', 'content': 'foo bar', 'created': '2016-01-27T15:17:10.375877'}

```
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer

json = JSONRenderer().render(serializer.data)
json
# b'{"email":"leila@example.com","content":"foo bar","created":"2016-01-27T15:17:10.375877"}'
```

so which one is it? Do I JSON or not JSON. This is what I currently have.

```
def get(self, request, format=None):
        searchcityqueryset = SearchCity.objects.all()
        neighborhoodqueryset = SearchNeighborhood.objects.all()
        serializedsearchcity = SearchCitySerializer(searchcityqueryset)
        serializedsearchneighborhood = SearchNeighborhoodSerializer(neighborhoodqueryset)
 jsonsearchcity = JSONRenderer().render(serializedsearchcity.data)
        jsonsearchneighborhood = JSONRenderer().render(serializedsearchneighborhood.data)
 return Response({
            'searchcity': jsonsearchcity,
            'searchneighborhood': jsonsearchneighborhood,
        })
```

Comment: this `# b'{"email` is json data its dumped json thats all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do it. 
From the [doc](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/responses/#response):

> Unlike regular HttpResponse objects, you do not instantiate Response
>   objects with rendered content. Instead you pass in unrendered data,
>   which may consist of any Python primitives.

Also [`JSONRenderer`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/settings/#default_renderer_classes) is default renderer class, which will be used to render.

So you can simple do this:

```
return Response({
    'cart': cart_serializer.data,
    'another': another_serializer.data,
    'yet_another_field': 'yet another value',
})
```